# PHP redirect issue with Safari

Tags: php, html, redirect, cookies, safari

I made a simple php redirect on my index page for first time users of the site to be redirected to firstvisit.htm where there are links to return to the index page

```html
<?php

if (!isset($_COOKIE['firsttime']))
{
    setcookie("firsttime", "no", 0);
    header('Location: firstvisit.htm');  

}
?>
```

In all browsers (didn't test IE) the code redirects properly to my firstvisit.htm page.

on that page are links  back to the index page. In all browsers but safari the links properly redirect. In Safari's case it displays the proper path in the url bar, but continues to show the firstvisit.htm page.

If the link is opened in a new tab it will function properly, and the cookie appears to be properly placed.

What would cause this and does anyone have a suggestion for a work around?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a redirect problem. As you say, firstvisit.htm is loaded normally on all browsers, but in Safari links on firstvisit.htm do not work. After loading firstvisit.htm, PHP is already long gone from the stage and has nothing to do with it. Sounds more like your local problem, maybe memory problem? Try the code on other hosts than localhost.

Comment: Do you have cookies disabled in Safari?  This would break for anyone who has cookies disabled.

Answer (score 0):

your cookie expires as soon as you set it.

try

```
setcookie("firsttime", "no", time() + 3600 * 24 * 30);
```